# Issue Login activity in Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-logcat

I have created a android application and its work properly. But now when try to login in my android application it display me the log cat error like:

```
>06-27 05:26:11.082: W/System.err(4308): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String
> cannot be converted to JSONObject
>06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
>06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
>06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):    at 
> //ERROR DISPLAY IN BACKGROUND
>   com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:446)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$SigIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                 06-27 05:26:11.092: W/System.err(4308):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308): java.net.MalformedURLException
>//ERROR DISPLAY ON URI
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:152)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.OpenHttpConnection(LoginActivity.java:710)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.DownloadImage(LoginActivity.java:741)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:665)
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
>         
>         //ERROR DISPLAY ON aSYNCTASK
>06-27 05:26:11.112: W/System.err(4308):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>06-27 05:26:11.122: W/System.err(4308): java.net.MalformedURLException
```

Comment: you have some Jsonexception. please show your code at where you used json or trying to parse something.

Comment: its a problem with your request and the Json handling.. the log cat tells you exactly where things are going wrong/ line 446 in your code.. please post the code for your AsyncTask